# Octave - Z axis vector arrowhead

Tags: matlab, octave

I have three vectors I want to display in a plot. `<1,0,0>`, `<0,1,0>`, and `<0,0,1>`.

This is my code:

```
    X = xlabel("X");
    Y = ylabel("Y");
    Z = zlabel("Z");
    axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1],'square');

    hold on
    vx = quiver3(0,0,0,1,0,0)
    hold on
    vy = quiver3(0,0,0,0,1,0)
    hold on
    vz = quiver3(0,0,0,0,0,1)

    set([vx,vy,vz], 'Color', 'black');
    set([vx,vy,vz], 'LineWidth', 4);
    set([vx,vy,vz], 'ShowArrowHead', 'on');
    grid on

    view([45,30]);
```

But it's plotting the following.

[image]

Another angle, shown below, tells me that it isn't just at a bad angle relative to the perspective. `<0,0,-1>` and `<0,0,-.5>` yield similar results.

[image]

Why won't it show the arrow for a vector only in `z`? Is there a way to make it show the arrow?

Comment: I'm using MATLAB, but that shouldn't be a difference I think, and it actually is bad angle. Try `view([45,30,25]);`

Comment: @ViG Still nothing. I should mention that I've spent eight hours "perfecting" my plot and its subsets, so I've seen it from pretty much every angle imaginable just by manipulating it with the Rotate tool.

Comment: Then I think it must be some error in octave, because with `view([45,30,25]);` I get [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ANeDmciDC2zGPpk5ARmjpFtfZUs6dHGE)

Comment: Regardless, thank you!

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer; don't edit it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported to the [Octave devs as a bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?53187#history). They are working on it. Thank you to @ViG for trying it in Matlab.